# (Terraform) Error 400: Invalid request: instance name (pg_instance)., invalid

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, devops, google-cloud-sql, terraform-provider-gcp

On **GCP**, I'm trying to create **a Cloud SQL instance** with **this Terraform code** below:

```
resource "google_sql_database_instance" "postgres" {
    name                = "pg_instance"
    database_version    = "POSTGRES_13"
    region              = "asia-northeast1"
    deletion_protection = false

    settings {
        tier      = "db-f1-micro"
        disk_size = 10
    }
}

resource "google_sql_user" "users" {
    name     = "postgres"
    instance = google_sql_database_instance.postgres.name
    password = "admin"
}
```

But I got this error:

> Error: Error, failed to create  instance pg_instance: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid request: instance name (pg_instance)., invalid

Are there any mistakes for **my Terraform code**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For **a Cloud SQL instance name**, **only lowercase letters, numbers, and hyphens are allowed and it must start with a letter**.

So, change this:

```
name = "pg_instance"
       # Underscore "_" is not allowed
```

To this:

```
name = "pg-instance"
       # Hyphen "-" is allowed
```

In addition, on **GUI**, you can see this message below under **the blank for instance ID("name" in Terraform)**:

> Use lowercase letters, numbers, and hyphens. Start with a letter.

[image]